# Jquery - change type = Checkbox instead of select in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox

I have this piece of code giving me a **select dropdown with its label**,

```
LeaveRuleAdapter.method('getFormFields', function() {
    return [
            [ "employee_can_apply", {"label":"Employees can apply for this leave type","type":"select","source":[["Yes","Yes"],["No","No"]]}]
});
```

I have 2 questions,

```
1. Is above codes are written on jquery or it's any jquery plugin ? 
2. Is there any way to include checkboxes insted of select.
```

( I'm a beginner in jquery, so dont mind if anything is wrong this question)

Comment: I guess [THIS (lib.js)](https://bitbucket.org/thilina/icehrm-opensource/commits/a7007624f522#chg-admin/leaves/lib.js) is the library which is using this code. You can check what's inside for further applications.

Comment: Yes i'm working on this Opensource HRM only !! I've checked all their other modules, ufortunately they didnt used any other types except text & select

Comment: If you want to get some `checkboxes` from some `forms` and do some stuff with them, you can edit your post by putting some `html` output code about the relevant part of your page. We may supply a solution with `jquery` or pure `js` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not jQuery
2. I don't know the code, but you could try this:

   ```
   LeaveRuleAdapter.method('getFormFields', function() { 
   return [["employee_can_apply", {"label":"Employees can apply for this leave type","type":"checkbox"}]]});
   ```

Comment: I've tried your solution, it's not working all i'm getting a blank screen.